# Drupal 7 view's operator "Is one of"

Tags: views

In Drupal 5 there was a possibility to filter our content type's NIDs using "is one of" operator. So I have a view where I only used one filter like

```
Node: Node ID -> Is One Of -> <?php return callback_function() ?>
```

This *callback_function()* returns an array of NIDs and my view works just perfect. While moving project to Drupal 7 I discovered that there is no more such operator. Does anybody knows any possibility to use this good old "Is One Of" operator? Thank you!

Comment: I just found that there was a *Views PHP Filter* module that allows to use PHP in filters, but it only exist for D5 and D6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to use *View PHP* module and *Global: PHP* field in filters.